# Loop over column names of a resultset

Tags: sql-server

I am using the following query to return all the column names belonging to tables in a database that are like name%

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE 'name%'
```

Now I would like to loop over the resultset of t.name and execute something like

```
Select * from t.name where c.name like 'abc%'
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: you will need to use `Dynamic SQL`

Comment: You'll need to generate a dynamic statement for this. I suggest against using a `WHILE` loop to do this; aggregate your string using `FOR XML PATH` or `STRING_AGG`. If you post some examples, and the expected results, we can help you more (you have enough reputation to know how to post a ["Reprex"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :) )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you need to generate and execute a dynamic statement:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) = N''

-- Dynamic statement
SELECT @stm = 
    @stm + CONCAT(
            N'SELECT * FROM ', 
            QUOTENAME(t.name), 
            N' WHERE ',
            QUOTENAME(c.name),
            N' LIKE ''abc%'';'
    )
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE 'name%'

-- Print and execute statement
PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```